# Small Chunks off my Tire Sidewall - Need Help! Fiat 500x

Tags: tires, maintenance, sidewall-damage

[image]I stupidly scraped a curb in my Fiat 500x going maybe 5mph so not fast at all but I scraped my rims and took these two small chunks out of my tire. You guys can see they are the size of my tiny fingertip, and not very deep.. I just got a flat tire two weeks ago (addmittedly by hitting a curb) and spent a lot of money, not only to be ridiculed by my husband who told me to drive more carefully (lovingly refers to my tires as "go kart tires"). I want you guy's opinion on if I need to get this tire looked at, no tire place around has these in stock and they are pricy so i'd rather not have to replace it. PSI is still the same and its not leaking air as far as I can tell. This happened earlier today, but I did drive on the highway just fine right after it happened. No tread issues. I just am trying to avoid getting my tire replaced for above reasons again because i think at that point my husband would flip! Anything I can do to secure/fix the tire?

Comment: A picture would help...

Comment: just posted one

Comment: It looks as if it is just surface damage. But I don't think you can do anything to hide them / fix them, you will have to just keep an eye on them - if they start to bulge then that will be evidence that the tyre is coming apart which means it will need to be replaced.

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike but might add that you could put a bit of soapy water on the divots and look for bubbles, to make sure you don't have a slow leak.

Comment: I did the soapy water, no bubbles. Checked PSI again, it's the same as it always is (35psi). Thanks jimmy and mike

Comment: I did the same about 4 months ago, three chunks though. I just keep an eye on it, looking to see if it starts to bulge in the hole. PSI the same. I drive the vehicle 150km a day. It has not caused me any probs so just keep an eye on it

Answer (score 1):

Not much, the tire would need to be replaced because there’s no good way to put an adhesive to fill the hole from what I know

Answer (score 1):

Damage to the sidewall of a tire is generally not repairable.

However, all you have really done is removed a tiny amount of material from a portion of the tire that is really cosmetic. It's made of the same rubber that the tire is, but the letters and stuff aren't really a functional part of the actual tire. Even if you carved the letters off with a knife it'd be safe to drive on. I do not consider this small amount of damage to warrant replacing the tire.

As others have commented, you can check for leaks by simply spraying soapy water on the tire. If your car has a functional TPMS system it should alert you if the tire loses air.

If you're still concerned, have a tire shop rotate the tire to the rear tires. A blowout or flat tire on the rear of a car is much less dangerous than one on the front.